# Using CGRECTMAKE what is the ratio to convert an iPhone 4 ..rect to an iphone 4s rect Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, screen-size, cgrectmake

I have used `CGRECTMAKE` to position an image onto the 'camera' screen and was wondering whether there is a calculation ratio to convert a 4 image placement to a 4s

Iphone 4 screen is 320 480
iphone 4s screen is 640 960

I have tried just doubling my values but that doesnt seem to work so thought someone may know a formula to convert them

I cannot use `AUTOLAYOUT` or PLACE IMAGES ON SCREEN in `storyboard` as i am placing an image onto the camera screen..have tried these but no joy

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I get your question correct but CGrectMake utilizes points, not pixels. Since the screen on i4 has the same size as the screen on i4s, There should be no implementation differences.

You should use 320*480 measures. The screen is devided into 320*480 points for i4/i4s

Comment: Also, both i4 and i4s has the same resolution so you should be okay.

Comment: By the way. Use 320*480 measures when placing your image